# duda sobre mamp en mac os high sierra

Tags: mysql, localhost

en mamp 5.3 me sale el siguiente error

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

en varios videos maneja que hay que modificar el archivo -my.ini- el cual revisando la carpeta de mamp no lo localizo agradecería alguien me oriente, gracias.

ps: en una macquina estoy en mac osX 10.11.6 el capitan, y en otra es mac os X high sierra

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Sigue las instrucciones en la [documentación](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/How-Tos/Change-the-password-of-the-MySQL-root-user/) :)

1. Abre la aplicación Terminal Mac OS en su directorio /Applications/Utilities.
2. Escriba (sin ejecutar) el siguiente comando:

   ```
   /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password [NewPassword]
   ```
3. Reemplace `[NewPassword]` por la nueva contraseña de root y ejecute el comando.
4. También hay que cambiar la configuración de phpMyAdmin y posiblemente sus propios scripts PHP para usar la nueva contraseña. Para cambiar la configuración de phpMyAdmin, edite el siguiente archivo y actualice la contraseña.

   ```
   /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
   ```

Comment: Ante todo gracias, fijate que ya hice lo que comentas, pero me sale seto al cambiar el password  

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!

te agradecería alguna orientación, ya que hasta el momento no había tenido problemas con mamp, gracias

Comment: Eso está diciendo que el servicio de MySQL no está iniciado...